# Any C/C++ library for analyzing SVG paths?

Tags: c++, c, svg

I need to analyze SVG files to identify paths that are connected, nested shapes etc. Is there any free C/C++ library that provides methods to analyze SVG paths - like finding if 2 paths overlap, whether a path lies entirely within a rectangle and so on? I tried searching on the web but couldn't find any close matches.

Comment: http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tackle it like a collision detection: check that path points overlap or are inside a shape using the same principles used for overlap/intersection/enclosure which are used in maths/physics/game programming and you should be fine.  If you need more pointers give me a shout.

**Addendum:**
For a simple well documented 2d collision detection library I would perhaps look at [Box2D](http://box2d.org/):  free, popular and well documented; or [OZCollide](http://www.tsarevitch.org/ozcollide/)  not bad free and easy to get to grips with from what I have seen.

In regards to general collision detection theres a site I have been using for years which is a handy documentation/knowledge base: [RealTimeRendering](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html)

There is also the [Corey O'Neils's](http://coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5) [collision detection kit](https://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/), however that would need you to port the relevant code to C++ from ActionScript.

Finally GameDev has a good link for learning about collision detection in 2d, its a post of a learning framework called [reni2d](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/584518-reni2d-library---added-shader-supportpixel-perfect-collision/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @GMasucci! Are there any free C/C++ libraries (not necessarily specific to SVG but capable of being used at a more generic level too) that can be used for identifying if 2 paths/shapes overlap or intersect? I am rather new to professional C/C++ and hence any pointers to such libraries would help. Or if you can provide pointers to sample code that is part of a larger library (say gaming library, which I cannot use directly) for such operations, that too would help.

Comment: Off the top of my head I would say the simplest way would be to make a vector of the point coordinates in each line and compare the position of each vector of points in 2d space to each other to determine proximity: ie
vLineOnePoints = pt(1,1), pt(1,2), pt(1,3) at world coordinates 1,1
vLineTwoPoints = pt(2,1), pt(2,2), pt(2,3) at world coordinates 0,1
when we check these we will find both overlap fully.
I shall look for a simple library to handle the collisions, but I have always written my own (they are at home and I am at work sadly), so bear with me as it will take me some time.

Comment: Hi @GMasucci - in case you were able to find a simple library for the above mentioned operations, please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: Will get on it tonight, if all else fails will write a short set of code to illustrate the principles.:)

Comment: @so2  hope you've had some luck, sorry still not had time to write a 2d collision library, however will be able to get on that saturday or sunday this week.